# Show for function $v$ that $\partial_1v_v=\partial_1v_1$ but $\nexists f$ with $v=\nabla f$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $v:\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb{R}^2$ be defined as
$$v(x,y)=\frac{(-y,x)}{x^2+y^2}.$$
Show that $\partial_1v_2=\partial_2v_1$, but no $f\in C^2(\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{0\},\mathbb{R})$ exists with $v=\nabla f$.

Comment: I wanted to show that $\partial_1v_2=\partial_2v_1$ by finding a parameterdependent integral representation of $v$, but I failed at it. I have no idea for the second part.

Comment: For the first part, direct calculation will do. For the second part, compute integral of $v$ over unit circle and recall properties of line integrals of potential vector fields.

Comment: What does it mean ? $\partial_1 v_2$

Comment: ok I got what it means

Comment: @MarcinŁoś: When it is centered at the origin, integral is zero which gives nothing ?

Comment: Yes, if $v$ were potential, integral would be 0. However, it isn't. That's the idea of proof.

Comment: but the result of integral is zero.

Comment: @mesel I think $\partial_1 v_2$ means the first partial derivative in the second variable of $v$